# How do I install Java 7 on Raspbian Buster?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-buster, java

I have a program that runs with Processing 2.2.1. I have downloaded Processing 2.2.1 from the Download page, but the Java included in the program is not compatible with the Raspberry Pi.

https://hackaday.io/project/7008-fly-wars-a-hackers-solution-to-world-hunger/log/21887-raspberry-pi-2-b-and-processing-221 I am following the article from this link and it seems that Java 7 is not available from Raspbian Buster, which is the version I'm using.

Is there any way to install Java 7 on Raspbian Buster? If not, how could I run Processing 2.2.1 on Raspbian?

The model I am using is Raspberry pi 3B+.

Comment: Is the code meant to run on a Pi? How is it incompatible? The solution is very unlikely to be to install an outdated version of Java.

Comment: No, the code is originally meant to run on a pc, but since it runs with Processing and as Processing can run on a Pi, I thought it was worth a try. Also the Java embedded in Processing is incompatible with the pi, so Processing fails to launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `libprocessing-core-java` package in Raspbian/RpiOS, but the current version  is 1.2.1-2 for both the 32-bit and 64-bit Buster repos.

I don't think you specially need to install java 7 for this.  The default JRE/JDK (8 on 32-bit and 11 on 64-bit) should be fine.

If you want to download a precompiled Processing newer than the distro version, use the **"Linux ARMv6hf"** package [from here](https://www.processing.org/download/) for version 3.5.3.  Hopefully it is backward compatible with code for 2.2.1 because there is no package for that (the plain "Linux 32-bit" will not work).  While Processing is apparently open source and therefore in theory could be compiled on the Pi, I think that a task best avoided.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply.